# how to use controller $scope in directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to implement Bootstrap Carousel with custom indicator using Angular, Carousel works well, but I am not able customize indicator.

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTouch']);
App.controller('Carousel', function($scope, $http, $element){
    $scope.myInterval = 5000;
    $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
    var slides = $scope.slides = [];

    $scope.slides = [{"img":"images\/bg-slider1.jpg","name":"GIFTS","class":"pinkbg"},{"img":"images\/bg-slider2.jpg","name":"FASHION","class":"ltgreen"},{"img":"images\/bg-slider1.jpg","name":"ASTROLOGY","class":"voilet"},{"img":"images\/bg-slider2.jpg","name":"ORGANIC","class":"green"},{"img":"images\/bg-slider1.jpg","name":"SPORTS","class":"yellow"},{"img":"images\/bg-slider2.jpg","name":"APPLIANCES","class":"grey"}];
    $scope.getNameByIndex = function(index){
        return $scope.slides[index]['name'];
    }
});

angular.module("template/carousel/carousel.html", []).run(["$templateCache", "$http", function($templateCache, $http) {
  $templateCache.put("template/carousel/carousel.html",
    "<div ng-mouseenter=\"pause()\" ng-mouseleave=\"play()\" class=\"carousel\" ng-swipe-right=\"prev()\" ng-swipe-left=\"next()\">\n" +
    "    <ol class=\"carousel-indicators\" ng-show=\"slides.length > 1\">\n" +
    "        <li ng-repeat=\"slide in slides | orderBy:indexOfSlide track by $index\" ng-class=\"{active: isActive(slide)}\" ng-click=\"select(slide)\" class='{{slide.class}}'>{{slide.name}}</li>\n" +
    "    </ol>\n" +
    "    <div class=\"carousel-inner\" ng-transclude></div>\n" +
    "</div>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

`$scope.slides` has additional attributes, `name` and `class` that needs to placed in indicator. how can I do that ?

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qwkJ84m6SB6slDxpe88s?p=preview)

Comment: could you add a working fiddle of your code

Comment: @Kushal Plunker added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off this caught my interest why the scope was not accessible. After a detailed analysis of the source code available on GitHub i found that the scope is being isolated in the library.

Plukr [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/npMsqiGwM3eBrvAdB2oU?p=preview)

On plunkr i have modified the library. File name : **angular-bootstrap-modified.js**

Read below for details.

**See the below code chunk from Git Hub:**

```
.directive('carousel', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    controller: 'CarouselController',
    controllerAs: 'carousel',
    require: 'carousel',
    templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
      return attrs.templateUrl || 'template/carousel/carousel.html';
    },
    scope: {
      interval: '=',
      noTransition: '=',
      noPause: '=',
      noWrap: '&'
    }
  };
}])
```

Newly created isolated scope variable for the directive inherits below data from its parent scope.

```
{
   interval: '=',
   noTransition: '=',
   noPause: '=',
   noWrap: '&'
}
```

Finally found that its a limitation from the library itself.

So i modified the library to achieve the solution. Below is what i changed

**Library code:**

```
scope: {
         interval: '=',
         noTransition: '=',
         noPause: '=',
         noWrap: '&',
         slidesData : '=slides'
    }
```

**and in HTML:**

```
<carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides" slides="slides">
```

After the modification, volla! now the directive isolated scope inherits the **slides** data too. Sweet!

**Info on Angular directives can be found** - [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Next tweaked the template code: All i did was change the **slides** reference to **slideData**

```
angular.module("template/carousel/carousel.html", []).run(["$templateCache", "$http", function($templateCache, $http) {
  $templateCache.put("template/carousel/carousel.html",
    "<div ng-mouseenter=\"pause()\" ng-mouseleave=\"play()\" class=\"carousel\" ng-swipe-right=\"prev()\" ng-swipe-left=\"next()\">\n" +
    "    <ol class=\"carousel-indicators\" ng-show=\"slidesData.length > 1\">\n" +
    "        <li ng-repeat=\"slide in slidesData | orderBy:indexOfSlide track by $index\" ng-class=\"{active: isActive(slide)}\" ng-click=\"select(slide)\" class='{{slide.class}}'>{{slide.name}} - {{$index}}</li>\n" +
    "    </ol>\n" +
    "    <div class=\"carousel-inner\" ng-transclude></div>\n" +
    "</div>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

Good now i can see the the **name** and **class** on `<ol></ol>` tag element rendered.

[image]

But now the switching animation doesnt happen on `<li>` .Below is the routine that compares the scope instead of index(i donno why?)

```
$scope.isActive = function(slide) {
     return self.currentSlide === slide;
};
```

I figured out by watching the expressions on my debugger console

[image]

### Final Words:

If you want to achieve it somehow.. You have to modify the library source itself. I would advice you to check out other sliders if you want customized sliders or use as is provided by the Angular Bootstrap library.

---

### Hope the above info explains the limitation. Happy Coding!

---

Also GitHub issue [logged](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4201)

---

### Update on this issue

Carousel customization will be implemented in the future versions as per the Github issue update

Comment: Thanks a mill, to looking into it and raising the issue in Github repo. fair enough.

Comment: hey, I managed to make it work as expected [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wrHTkoYBX7oKAVvXvyhk?p=preview). actually (as I understand), template needs `slides` which is binded in carousel .. `slideData` doesn't have any link with that. 

so I've just used `slideData` with `$index` to get the value - nice hack!!

Comment: Thats nice. Heads up!

Comment: I'm also facing some issues because of this isolated scope. I want to call a method of outside controller from the slide. How can it be achieved ? Any idea?

Comment: I have found that actual attribute is been added with the uib-carousel slide. Will it be helpful in my case ?

Comment: it should be.. But as per the library author this was to be implemented as a enhancement. Please take the latest build and check it. You can optionally follow in the github issue link for the updates.